# JMSProvider connection to remote WMQ from IIB 10

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I would like to make a JMS connection from IIB 10 to a Websphere MQ 9.
The Architecture is: 
IIB 10 on linux server A
WMQ 9 on linux server B.
current JMSProvider settings that I have defined are providing option for connecting only to QM that runs on the same machine.
How can I specify (by command) the IIB to connect to remote MQ with JMS ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason you would not connect using normal MQ Input and MQ Output nodes, these can work as clients as well.

Comment: The applicative requirements does not allow not using JMS unfortunately..
So we have to use soap over JMS for this scenario and therefore provide mq queue for the JMS use.

Comment: Do you just mean that the app that will read the messages from the MQ 9 queue manager expects them to have a JMS header (RFH2)?  If that is the case IIB can still provide that.  What specific requirement makes you think you can not use the normal MQ Input/Output nodes?